# javascript - check if object has child property

Tags: javascript

Assuming an object like this

```
var a = {
  b: {
    c: [
      {
        e: 'hello'
      },
      {
        f: 'bye'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to check if `e` is valid.

Currently I am using multiple `if` conditions like

```
if (typeof a !== 'undefined' && typeof a.b !== 'undefined' && typeof a.b.c !== 'undefined' && typeof a.b.c[0] !== 'undefined') {
      console.log('value of e ' + a.b.c[0].e);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying but you can use this to make sure there is "e" value

```
a = a || {};
var e = a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c[0] && a.b.c[0].e;
```

or you can use

```
a = a || {};
if (a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c[0] && a.b.c[0].e){
   console.log('value of e ' + a.b.c[0].e);
}
```

if you are sure about values, i like this usage.

```
var e = a.b.c[0].e || "no value";
// "hello"

var e = a.b.c[0].d || "no value";
// "no value"
```